# Relevance search in Classic and UUI

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-uci

I am facing an issue in the UUI (Unified Interface) where the relevance search has one less record type showing when compared to using the Classic UI.

I have followed all the steps in enabling the relevance search and specifying the entity's field to be indexed for search but it is only working when in classic view.

Can anyone confirm if the relevance search in UUI can show more than two record type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you complete the below steps:

1. Enable it for mobile from the entity settings page

[image]

2. Add the entity in UCI app Artifacts

[image]

[Read more](https://www.tutorialkart.com/dynamics365/add-entity-assets-artificat-dynamics-365-app/)

Comment: Thanks Arun! The adding of entity in the app designer works!